# Android - vertical orientation works, horizontal orientation blank

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-orientation

I am implementing a ViewPagerIndicator that works as expected in vertical orientation. When I test in horizontal orientation, either by switching at run-time (physically turning the phone) or when the app starts in horizontal mode (phone was horizontal before the app started) I get a blank white space where the ViewPagerIndicator should be. I have a layout/main.xml and layout-land/main.xml with a few buttons that are displaying as expected (stacked vertically in vertical mode, as a grid in horizontal mode). When I press the "edit" button, I launch the edit activity:

```
public class ATEditActivity extends Activity {
    static final int OFFSCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT = 5;
ViewPager pager = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit);

        int iPage = 2;  // set the page based on caller's intentions
        Bundle bndlExtras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bndlExtras != null) {
        iPage = bndlExtras.getInt("PAGE");
        }

        ATViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ATViewPagerAdapter(this);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(OFFSCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.TitlePageIndicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);
        indicator.setCurrentItem(iPage);
    }
}
```

edit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etName"
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:hint="@string/name" />

<com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/TitlePageIndicator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.MyTitlepageIndicator" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/awesomepager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any thoughts on why the ViewPagerIndicator would not display in horizontal mode? Is more information needed?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to override `onConfigurationChanged()` see [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) as your app needs to retrieve the resources again and draw everything.

Comment: If I've read the onConfigurationChanged documentation correctly, I would implement a storage class that extends Object and have getters and setters for all the data I want stored (but not the views and adapters that will be recreated in onCreate). Then in onCreate I look for the stored data and load it if it is found. Is that about right?

Comment: You could do it that way or if you didn't care just store global variables in your app and you can get a reference to your app and access the variables in this way. Or you save just enough data in savedInstance so you can use that information to restore the layout with relevant values. Another thing you could is just set your config to stop it from destroying your activity and restarting it again, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges

Comment: I have finally gotten to doing some testing on the onConfigurationChanged() mechanism. This function is successfully called as the Toast is being displayed. I can do some work to setup the ViewPagerAdapter. The TitlePageIndicator still does not display when the phone is in horizontal mode. I have commented out the code that creates the TitlePageIndicator object and I do not see it in either mode so I know I'm in the right place.

Comment: @Imhotep That's good progress, sounds like you are on the right track, understanding the app life cycle is crucial to handle the multiple ways your app can be modified by an user action.

Comment: With all the debugging I've been doing I can see that the TitlePageIndicator is being created and all the defaults are being set. But the code never gets into the TitlePageIndicator.onDraw(). I don't understand all the internals of how TitlePageIndicator and ViewPager interact but I think the problem lies somewhere between the two. The TPI is not showing even when the app is started in horizontal mode. I've confirmed the same behavior in both a horizontal emu and directly on my phone in horizontal mode prior to launching the app.

Comment: I've now managed to get to where the titles will display. I had to comment out the EditText in the above edit.xml. But that's as far as I've managed to figure things out. The VPI still doesn't display the layouts I've defined for use inside the VPI.

Answer (score 0):

After three or four days of trying everything I could imagine, I finally decided there must have been something really messed up in my project so I created a new project that only had the minimal amount of code necessary to get the ViewPagerIndicator working. The new project is now working with both orientations "out-of-the-box". I have no idea what caused my old project to go haywire with only the horizontal orientation but I will get the new project on track and up to speed in short order now that it is working as expected.